# View tar cf pipe to openssl progress with pv progress viewer

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl

I would like to view the progress of an encryption with [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), the progress view command.

Currently have a bash script that will a take folder name, tar it, encrypt with openssl,
and save it to a file with this line:

```
tar cf - $1 | openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -out $1.tar.aes
```

It asks for a password, confirms the password and does its stuff.
I am able to decrypt with this command in a bash script, where `$1` is `archive.tar.aes`:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in $1 | tar -xf -
```

What I want to do is add the `pv` command, specify the archive size (so that pv can computer the ETA) with:

```
pv -n -s `du -s jazz | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

and view the progress of the encryption.

What i am trying now is this:

```
tar cf - $1 | pv -n -s `du -s jazz | awk '{ print $1 }'` |  openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -out $1.tar.aes
```

It doesn't seem to work. 
What happens is the openssl command asks for a password and before i enter one, pv starts
spitting out the progress. (Not accurate though)

It's probably the way i have the pipes organized. Do i need to group them differently?
Or am i missing something about pipes?

Could you demonstration how to do what i am trying to achieve here?

Any input or advice appreciated.
Thanks.

### Update 1:

With the reorganzied pipes from @damienfrancois, `pv` still spits out stuff before I
have entered the openssl password. Here is the output i get now:

```
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:   0 B 0:00:01 [   0 B/s] [>                                                            ]  0% ETA 0:00:00
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:   0 B 0:00:02 [   0 B/s] [>                              0 B 0:00:07 [   0 B/s] [>                                                            ]  0% ETA 0:00:00

bad password read
```

I managed to stop the password interruption with `-W` flag for `pv` This tells it to wait
until it has gotten the first on the pipe. With that, I am able to enter the password alright
but the progress is very inaccurate. I am getting readings like `51199%`:

```
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
 335MiB 0:00:02 [ 126MiB/s] [========================================================] 51199%
```

After that i get a different problem, The terminal gets messed up so when i press enter at
the prompt, it doesn't take me to a newline, It just prints out the prompt in front
of the last prompt like this:

```
localhost:crypto-utils rudker$ localhost:crypto-utils rudker$
```

This may have something to do with pv not setting the terminal variables back correctly
like what can happen if you don't call `endwin()` in ncurses

Any Ideas how i can get decent progress indication for what I'm trying to do here?
- Without messing up the terminal.

The line in the bash script up to date is:

```
tar cf - $1 |  openssl aes-256-cbc -salt | pv -W -s `du -s jazz | awk '{ print $1 }'` > $1.tar.aes
```

Comment: What about the pv output is inaccurate in this scenario? tar is going to start spooling data to the pipe as soon as it can which means pv is going to start seeing it before openssl starts reading the data (especially since openssl needs a password before it can do anything with the data).

Comment: If you see my update, everything is working except that the `pv` percentage is way off (51199% on completion, no progress bar movement) and pv is messing up the terminal settings. (Pressing enter at a prompt doesn't take you to a newline.)

Comment: @Rudker Your problem is, that size is expected to be in MB if no unit is given. This is simply fixed by adding `-h` (Human-readable) to the `du` command :)

Answer (score 2):

You can reorganise the pipes so that `openssl` starts before `pv`:

```
tar cf - $1 |  openssl aes-256-cbc -salt | pv -n -s `du -hs jazz | awk '{ print $1 }'` > $1.tar.aes
```

The above lets `openssl` write to stdout so that it goes through pv before going to disk, but after being decrypted. The accuracy of the file size might not be perfect though.